# Is it possible to get user email with loginname programmatically in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a search function that returns the email for a user when I have the user's ID

```
private string getUserEmail(string userID)
{
    string userEmail = null;
    SPGroupCollection collGroups = SPContext.Current.Web.Groups;
    int userIDint = Convert.ToInt32(userID);
    foreach (SPGroup oGroup in collGroups)
    {
        userEmail = oGroup.Users.GetByID(userIDint).Email.ToString();
    }
    return userEmail;
}
```

with Users I can do either GetByID or GetByEmail but what should I do if I have the domain name such as MyDomain\myUsername and want the email for that user?

Any help or links would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414398.aspx

```
SPContext.Current.Web.AllUsers["loginname"].Email
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx

```
SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser("loginname").Email
```